# Different class name in WinForm and WebService

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

I have a class defined that I use for loading information of the database as BO. I use the same DLL (I have it in a different project) for both, the WinForm app and the WebService.

The problem is that when I retrieve the info executing the WS, the name of the class comes with the namespace and the WS name included, and makes me convert from one object to another... but IS THE SAME!!!

```
List<**Trevo.FrameWork.MiAutoWS.ParametrosBOL**> oWs = obj.Parametros();

List<**ParametrosBOL**> x = new List<ParametrosBOL>();
foreach (Trevo.FrameWork.MiAutoWS.ParametrosBOL o in oWs)
{
   ParametrosBOL oNuevo = new ParametrosBOL();
   oNuevo.IDEmpresa = o.IDEmpresa;
   oNuevo.IDTipo = o.IDTipo;
   oNuevo.Tipo = o.Tipo;
   oNuevo.IDCodigo = o.IDCodigo;}
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding a using stement, like 'using Trevo.FrameWork.MiAutoWS;'

Comment: @CSharpie. I already tried. The problem is that for the compiler, are different types. See the message: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Trevo.FrameWork.MiAutoWS.ParametrosBOL>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ParametrosBOL>'"

Comment: Does this apply to you? [Reuse types in referenced assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb628653(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @Silvermind. Great article! Thanks! But... still not working.

Comment: @Nane yes you have the `reuse types...` problem. Remove the service reference and add it again, making sure the `Reuse types...` CheckBox is Checked in the `Add Service Reference` popup.

Comment: @HighCore. Did it. The "Reuse types..." is chequed. Tested both: Reuse all and Reuse selected, but still not working.